# Why when I upgrade from pillow 9.2.0 to 9.3 or 9.4 in a venv does my program break?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, version-control, python-imaging-library

When I upgrade my Pillow 9.2.0 package matplotlib seems to get corrupted. Is there a way to get around this?

**And I receive the following errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\_", line 11, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\_", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File  "C:\Users\_", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\_", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, _cm, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Users\_", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Users\_", line 138, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Users\_", line 49, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found
```

**Python version 3.10.9**

**working venv **

1. ---

```
1. altgraph                  0.17.2
1. contourpy                 1.0.7
1. cycler                    0.11.0
1. dicom-numpy               0.6.3
1. fonttools                 4.33.3
1. future                    0.18.2
1. kiwisolver                1.4.2
1. matplotlib                3.6.3
1. numpy                     1.24.2
1. packaging                 21.3
1. pefile                    2021.9.3
1. Pillow                    9.2.0
1. pip                       23.0
1. pydicom                   2.3.1
1. pyinstaller               5.0.1
1. pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.4
1. pyparsing                 3.0.8
1. python-dateutil           2.8.2
1. pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
1. scipy                     1.10.0
1. setuptools                65.5.0
1. six                       1.16.0
```

I tried to uninstall Pillow 9.2 and Matplotlib and install the newest Matplotlib alone.  The install of Matplotlib installs Pillow 9.4 and this also breaks my code.  I can repair the code by uninstalling Pillow 9.4 and installing Pillow 9.2.

**Something to try?**
The only thing that I use PIL for is to set PixelData in a Dataset object tag.  Is there another way to do this without using Pillow?

```
    from PIL import Image
    ds.PixelData = Image.fromarray(ct_slice).tobytes() #write slice to file`
```